# Triggering faults on Cortex-M7 MCU

Tags: c, gcc, arm, cortex-m

I wrote a Fault Handler for an ARM Cortex-M7 microcontroller project and now I have the interesting yet somewhat challenging task of testing it with different types of faults. We have a simple self-test system and I just need to add some functions which trigger the faults, so I can examine and validate the "core-dump" data the Handler saves.

This is what I have so far:

```
    /* Usage fault, dereference NULL pointer. */
    
    void test_1(void)
    {
        uint32_t *test_addr = (uint32_t *)NULL;

        *test_addr = 5;
    }
    
    /* Memory fault (MPU), try to execute from non-executable memory. */

    __attribute__ ((section(".data_RAM2.no_exe")))
    void test_2(void)
    {
        LogErr("Memory fault - test failed!");
    }
    
    /* Usage fault, execute invalid instruction. */
    
    static const int fault_inv_inst __attribute__((section(".text#"))) = 0xFFFFFFFF;

    void test_3(void)
    {
        void (*inv_inst_p)(void) = (void (*)(void))(&fault_inv_inst);
        inv_inst_p();
    }
    
    /* Bus fault, access invalid address. */
    
    #define FAULT_INV_INST_ADDR_BUS_ACC     0xDEADBEEF
    
    void test_4(void)
    {
        return *(volatile uint32_t *)FAULT_INV_INST_ADDR_BUS_ACC;
    }
```

UART Output:

```
    Running test 1:
    Critical! Fault: Usage Fault
    Fault flags: UNDEFINSTR
    
    Running test 2:
    Critical! Fault: Memory Fault
    Fault flags: IACCVIOL
    
    Running test 3:
    Critical! Fault: Usage Fault
    Fault flags: UNDEFINSTR
    
    Running test 4:
    Critical! Fault: Bus Fault
    Fault Address: 0xDEADBEEF
    Precise Fault
    Fault flags:
```

It would be great to get other faults, I would especially like to get an imprecise bus fault but I can't seem to be able to generate it.

Comment: you may have to work with the chip vendor (not arm, the chip vendor) to generate some of these, if they even provided features to create faults for testing purposes.  bus related faults basically.  Otherwise you have to the verification by inspection instead of by demonstration.

Comment: The vendor does not provide anything extra other than the standard ARM fault support. But I reckon there must be some SW conditions that generate faults, common to all Cortex-M cores (like some of the stuff I wrote above).

Comment: There is a complete list of faults, and the conditions that cause them, in the Armv7-M Architecture Reference Manual, section B1.5.14.  Some of them involve things like having an exception handler cause an exception.  There's also breakpoints and SVC if you want to count those.

Comment: Searching for "imprecise" there is a mention that PLD or PLI on an invalid address might cause an imprecise fault.  The odds might be better if you precede it with a bunch of valid PLD/PLI, which thus may still be in flight when the invalid one is executed, causing it to be queued for later.  But it also explains that it is hardware-dependent whether imprecise bus faults can happen at all.